# adding a class in the first iteration of a loop

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, loops, carousel

I have the following loop to create my carousel, however I need to add the active class on the first iteration only:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'homepage_banner',
'orderby'=>'menu_order','order'=>'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

echo '<div class="item active"> <img alt="';
echo the_title();
echo'" data-src="" src="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption"><h2>';
    echo the_title();
      echo '</h2><p>';
      echo the_content();
      echo'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';

endwhile;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply like this:

```
<?php

 $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'homepage_banner',
     'orderby'=>'menu_order','order'=>'ASC');
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 $active = ' active'; //<============== updated line 1
 while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

     echo '<div class="item'. $active .'"> <img alt="';

     echo the_title();
     echo'" data-src="" src="">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption"><h2>';
             echo the_title();
             echo '</h2><p>';
             echo the_content();
             echo'</p>
         </div>
     </div>
     </div>';
     $active = ''; //<============== updated line 2

 endwhile;

?>
```